# Getting all possible combinations of 2 lists

Tags: php

I have 2 lists:

- List1 has the elements (a,b,c,d,e)
- List2 has the elements (1,2,3)

I have to calculate all possible combinations using all the elements of the 2 arrays:

- Combinaton 1: a1, b2, c3, dNULL, eNULL
- Combination 2: a1, bNULL, c2, d3, eNULL

And so on. The length of the lists is dynamic. How do I write the function in PHP necessary to solve this problem?

Comment: I assume that the shorter list will be filled up with `null` values, right?

Answer (score 1):

A simple nested loop works:

```
$sets = array();
foreach ($list1 as $elm1){
    foreach ($list2 as $elm2){
        $sets[] = array($elm1, $elm2);
    }
}
```

If you need the null versions too, pad the arrays first:

```
$max = max(count($list1), count($list2));
$list1 = array_pad($list1, $max, null);
$list2 = array_pad($list2, $max, null);
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. But this really doesnt help. Every combination should pair all the elements. Not just one element of the arrays.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Can you give a full example with expected output?

Answer (score 0):

This is called "cartesian product", php man page on arrays http://php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php shows some implementations (in comments).

```
function array_cartesian() {
    $_ = func_get_args();
    if(count($_) == 0)
        return array(array());
    $a = array_shift($_);
    $c = call_user_func_array(__FUNCTION__, $_);
    $r = array();
    foreach($a as $v)
        foreach($c as $p)
            $r[] = array_merge(array($v), $p);
    return $r;
}
```

Example:

```
$cross = array_cartesian(
    array('apples', 'pears',  'oranges'),
    array('steve', 'bob')
);
```

To see the output:

```
print_r($cross);
```

Answer (score 0):

1 -- get all permutations of list1 as X, the longer list

2-- for each element in X, create a mapping on list2

3 -- time complexity: X*list2